# Question about XmlSerializer in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have the following classes in C# that I want to serialize:

> Item
>
> ProjectItem : Item
>
> Folder : Item
>
> Project (Contains a collection of
>   Item, that may be either a ProjectItem
>   or a Folder)

When I serialize a "Project", I get the following...

```
<Project>
  <Item xsi:type="Folder">
   <Name>MyFolder</Name> 
  </Item>
</Project>
```

While I'd like something like...

```
<Project>
  <Folder>
   <Name>MyFolder</Name> 
  </Folder>
</Project>
```

Do you have any idea about how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add some attributes like this to your Project property:

```
[XmlArray]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="ProjectItem", Type=typeof(ProjectItem))]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Folder", Type=typeof(Folder))]
public List<Item> Project
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can control naming by attributes:

```
public class MyEntity{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folder")]
    public someType ProjectItem{get;set;};
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't completetely solved my problem. The "Project" property of type "Project" may contain either Folder or ProjectItem, so I can't assume it will always be "Folder" for instance.